# CodeIgniter - Unable to load libraries in subfolders

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running across a strange situation. I'm working on a portion of an existing CodeIgniter app. I don't know how extensively the app has been modified, but my understanding is that core code has not been modified - the client has simply added more code on top of the core code.

I've put a library into a subfolder, and I'm trying to load it, but it's failing. To make sure it wasn't something INSIDE the library, I just tried the same thing using an empty SampleLibrary and got the same results.

So, this works:

```
$this->load->library('SampleLibrary');
```

But if I move the same library into subfolder "xyz" and update the code, it does NOT work:

```
$this->load->library('xyz/SampleLibrary');
```

When it fails, it doesn't seem to throw an exception. It simply shows a message on the page:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: xyz/samplelibrary
```

...and exits at that point. I've added a try/catch block and the catch code never runs. I cannot change the config.php to change any logging parameters.

Any thoughts on how to get more debug information about what's going on?

Comment: Also, two more bits of information: 

#1. This is on CodeIgniter 1.5.4. 

#2. Other load-> commands like load->model and load->helper work with subfolders just fine. Library seems to be the only type with this problem.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try answer below? I believe you'll have to create a separate file that calls the subfolder, you won't be able to load the file directly from `this->load->library`

Comment: You could try using hmvc you can load libraries in sub folders there I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to take a quick look at what the load->library code was doing. Apparently, it was trying a few varieties and failing:

ucfirst() was running on the incoming value, so it was initially looking for:

```
libraries/Xyz/SampleLibrary.php
```

...because I was on Linux, the caps mattered and it couldn't find the folder with the upper case name.

It also searched for the entire thing lower-cased:

```
libraries/xyz/samplelibrary.php
```

So it was missing the real filename, which was:

```
libraries/xyz/SampleLibrary.php
```

So I guess I just need to use Xyz for my folder name. Weird, but oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to load the library:

```
$this->load->library('SampleLibrary');
$vars_returned_here = $this->sample_library_function($data);
```

Create a file called SampleLibrary.php in your libraries folder.  In that file:

```
class Samplelibrary {

    private $CI;
    private $errors;
    private $response;

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
    }

    function sample_library_function($data) {
        require('xyz/SampleLibrary');
            //do your thing
            //$vars = ...
            return $vars;

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. It's a bit of a long story, but it's essentially a development restriction policy enforced by this client for this project, so my libraries have to reside in subfolders. I've found other sites/questions/answers that indicate this should be possible...